# curl: (7) Failed to connect to GoogleHomeのip port 8091: 接続を拒否されました

Tags: network, curl

よろしくお願いいたします。
google-home-notifierを用いてgoogle-homeに好きな言葉を
話させようと考えております。

環境　virtualbox
ゲストOS　ubuntu

google-home-notiierのexample.jsを実行し別コンソール上にて

```
curl -X POST -d "text= お疲れ様" http://GoogleHomeのip:8091/google-home-notifier
```

を実行したところ

```
curl: (7) Failed to connect to GoogleHomeのip port 8091: 接続を拒否されました
```

と表示されてしまいました。

どのようにすれば接続できるかご教示いただけると大変助かります。

Answer (score 1):

[google-home-notiier](https://github.com/noelportugal/google-home-notifier) の `example.js` だとすると、アクセスすべきはGoogle Homeでは無く、この `example.js` で起動したサーバーではないでしょうか。

もしそうならば、「GoogleHomeのip」ではなく、`example.js` を実行中のマシンのIPアドレスを指定して下さい。READMEに、

```
Endpoints:
    http://192.168.1.20:8091/google-home-notifier
    https://xxxxx.ngrok.io/google-home-notifier
```

のように表示されると書いてありますが、もしかしたら表示されるIPは間違っているのかもしれません。

Comment: IPアドレスをそのように変更いたしたところ、googlehomeから音声が出るようになりました。ありがとうございました。